# Creating Multi Dimesnional Array from 1D array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Hello I am trying to create a simple array that contains a '10' 3x3 matrices. So I tried to create a 1D matrix that has 1 x 10 values. Then I tried assigning a 3x3 matrix in to each of the 10 slots in the 1D matrix. I am quite sure my syntax is wrong and matlab (I don't think allows this) but I couldn't find too much info to pre assign such array and I just started learning about matlab. Here is my attempt:

```
big_array = zeros(1,10) # creates 1x10 1d array
for i = 1:10
   big_array(i) = zeros(3,3); #supposedly? assign 3x3 matrix in to each of the 10 slots
end
big_array # received an error
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you want an array of 10 3x3 matrices, you would typically want to use a multidimensional array from the start.

```
big_array = zeros(10,3,3);
```

You can access the `i`'th matrix using `big_array(i,:,:)`.

If you really do want a one-dimensional array of 3x3 matrices, you need to use a `cell` array.

```
big_array = {};
for i = 1:10
   big_array{i} = zeros(3,3);
end
big_array
```

You can now access the `i`'th matrix using `big_array{i}`.

Answer (score 1):

A small clarification - If all your slots must contain submatrices with the same size, then you can use very simple expression:

```
big_array = zeros(3,3,10) % (first dimension - rows, second dimension - columns, third dimension - bands or arrays)
```